# Idiomatic Scala way to come a list of Eithers into a Left or Right depending on the lists content

Tags: functional-programming, scala, either

I have a list of Eithers

```
val list: List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Right(5), Left("abc"), Right(42))
```

As a result I want a `Right` if everything in the list is a `Right` else I want a `Left`. This sounds like the list should be biased (e.g. use `Try` instead) but let's assume it isn't or shouldn't be.

The content of the resulting `Right` or `Left` will always be the same (e.g. a string, see blow) - only the Container shall differ. E.g. with the list above we want to create a string from this list so the result should be of a `Left` like `Left("Right(5) -> Left(abc) -> Right(42)")`. If we had another `Right(12)` instead of the `Left("abc")` it should be `Right("Right(5) -> Right(12) -> Right(42)")`.

I could manually check if there is at least one `Left` in the list and branch with an if to create a `Left` or a `Right` as result, but I wonder: is there a more Scala-like way to do it?

Comment: What about an empty list, is that a `Right`?

Comment: @Bergi that would still count as a `Right` so as long as every other value is also a `Right` the output should still be a `Right` of `Right`s

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in a functional way with a `foldLeft`.

Basically in the fold function you fold using the rules

```
Right + Right => Right
SomethingElse => Left
```

In scala code:

```
def string(a: Any, b: Any): String = if (a.toString.isEmpty)
   s"${b.toString}" else s"${a.toString} -> ${b.toString}"

def transform[T, U](list: List[Either[T, U]]) = 
  list.foldLeft[Either[String, String]](Right("")) {
    case (Right(a), bb @ Right(b)) => Right(string(a, bb))
    case (Right(a), bb) => Left(string(a, bb))
    case (Left(a), bb) => Left(string(a, bb))
  }

transform(List(Right(5), Left("abc"), Right(42)))
// prints Left(Right(5) -> Left(abc) -> Right(42))
transform(List(Right(5), Right("abc"), Right(42)))
// prints Right(Right(5) -> Right(abc) -> Right(42))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Either` is actually used in sence of ***Value** or **Error*** in Haskell.
But scala `Either`'s design does not allow it's use as "Error Monad". That was fixed in [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) via [`\/` type](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0-SNAPSHOT/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.$bslash$div). Thing you want to basically implemented via `sequence` extension of `Traverse` types. 
So prefix your code with:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

and get your result like

```
type Error[A] = String \/ A
val mlist = (list map \/.fromEither).sequence[Error, Int]
```

or even oneline type currying:

```
val mlist = (list map \/.fromEither).sequence[({type E[A] = String \/ A})#E, Int]
```